# Magento 2: Custom Category page

Tags: magento2, category, layout, magento-2.0

Could anyone let me know where the Category page layout XML is located, so I can created a custom layout and override the 'out of the box' layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several layout files available for the category page in Magento 2, the main files being located under `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout` folder:

- `catalog_category_view.xml`
- `catalog_category_view_type_default.xml` adds the left side navigation bar
- `catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children.xml` does not add the left side navigation bar

Comment: I am creating a new custom category page in which I have just used list.phtml file in my module. But its not working. Can you tell me how I can create a new category page through custom **Product Collection**?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for creating different layout of one category different from other then :

You need to create a xml file `catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml` under your theme > Magento_Catalog > layout and change list file.

For detail :
http://sumankc.com/2016/12/10/different-template-for-different-categories-in-magento-2-category_id-layout-handle-in-m2/

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution can be brittle, as it is based on autoincrement IDs rather than meaningful domain identifiers. It requires autoincrement sync among all environments.